# Consumer do not join a consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am using kafka-python and I want to consume messages from a topic. For monitoring reasons, I want to create a consumer and assign it to a consumer'group.
I am using the following functions:

```
    server = KafkaConsumer(application.name, bootstrap_servers = str(ip_address)+':'+str(ip_port) , client_id =str(application.name)+'_dispatcher', group_id='xxxxxx')
    server.subscribe(topics=[application.name])
```

However, when monitoring the consumer groups using:

```
bash kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --all-groups
```

I still see that the consumer is not added to the consumer groups and the consumer group is not rebalancing. Could someone explain to me what is the problem with Kafka?

Comment: Does your consumer actually consume? You cannot just "add to a group", it needs to actually poll first. Also, what if you `--describe --group xxxxx`?

Comment: I just create the consumer and I try to poll messages from this consumer, but it does not consume these messages. It is weird to me as I know that the topic exists, and also because I have a producer which produces messages. Also, one question, if there is no consumer for a topic, how is it possible to collect the lag of that topic? It is weird to me that I can collect it only if there exists a consumer for that topic.

Comment: Consumers default to read from the end of the topic, where there is nothing to consume. You can also query a topic for all partitions, and assign the consumer, rather than subscribe, thereby not using consumer group protocol... For lag, you can use external tooling like Burrow to simply get lag for all groups. Combine that with Prometheus+Grafana to visualize...

Comment: By checking the log of Kafka, I see that the Broker sees just the first consumer created that is joining the group. Is it possible that as the two are created within the same minute maybe the broker does not see the latter created? If so, do you know a solution to the problem?

Comment: Not sure I follow, but if your topic only has one partition, then only one consumer can read from that in the same group.

Comment: I know this, but it is not the problem: I have a topic with a partition, and I created a consumer in a consumer group, however, it seems like the consumer is not created thus also the messages are not consumed

Comment: But **how many** partitions? You say "a partition", implying one, therefore, as I said, only one consumer will be able to read anything... Please show your command to create the topic. In order to create a [mcve], please tell us what versions of Python, Kafka, and kafka-python you're running. You've also not included your full code with the processing loop... Have you also tried not using IP+port? Are you not consuming from localhost like your describe command shows?

Comment: Wrote you in the answer below

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information, not respond in an answer. Personally, I have not used Python kafka client with multi-threading to be able to help.